# Cache de Servidor Ubuntu com Nginx

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, servidor, nginx, cache

Estou com um problema de Cache em meu Servidor Ngnix com Wordpress

O site está usando atualmente um WebService e SESSION do PHP, o WebService me traz as informações do usuário e armazeno na sessão, porém o usuário pode alterar os dados dele, quando ele atualiza os dados a variável SESSION também é atualizada, mas "não muda"! Mesmo limpando o cache do browser, só muda após limpar o cache do servidor utilizando as ferramentas do Nginx

Existe alguma funcionalidade do PHP para limpar esse cache?

Ou como posso arrumar o servidor para não armazenar cache de paginas especificas?